# How to calculate $E[X\cdot Y]$?

Tags: probability

Say we throw a dice $n$ times. I have two random variables: X represents the number of times we got 2 and Y represents the number of times we got 3. How do I calculate the expected value $E[X\cdot Y]$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $E(g(X, Y)) = \sum g(x, y) \cdot p(x, y)$.

Answer (score 1):

First find  $\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$.

For that see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2580800/75923).

Then find $\mathsf{E}XY$ on base of: $$\mathsf{E}XY=\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)+\mathsf{E}X\mathsf{E}Y$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
E[X\cdot Y] = \sum_{i,j} i j \, Prob(X=i,Y=j) = 6^{-n}\sum_{i,j} i j {n \choose i}{n-i \choose j} 4^{n-i-j}
$$